# How to filter DTrace output for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, dtrace

I am learning [DTrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace), and it is very powerful tool. But one problem is that DTrace outputs too much information and most of those are NS classes.

But my question is how I can filter system classes if users' classes do not have proper prefix?

(There was a similar Stack Overflow question for this topic, *[How to detect without the system method or system framework with DTrace on Mac OS X?]*.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTrace uses [Filename generation](http://uw714doc.sco.com/en/SDK_tools/_Filename_Generation.html)-like syntax to specify probe names. E.g. you could specify first characters of a class name by using brackets `[` and `]`.

E.g. if you want to filter all NS* classes:

```
objc$target::[ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ]*:entry (N is removed)
objc$target::N[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRTUVWXYZ]*:entry (S is removed)
```

But you have to repeat it for each prefix Apple uses, like CA, IK etc.